# jQuery slideUp only works for the first element

Tags: jquery, slideup

I've got a problem with `slideUp`. Only one element (the first one) is sliding up. Please give me a hand. Thanks. Below is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#load').hide();
});
$(function() {
    $("#del").click(function() {
        $('#load').fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
        $('#load').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

And here is the markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <div id="load" align="center"><img src="images/loading.gif" width="28" height="28"     align="absmiddle"/> loading...</div>
        <tr><td>    
            <span>Ashley Ford</span><br/></td>  
            <td><a href="#" id="del">x</a>  
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <span>Ashley Ford</span><br/></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="del">x</a>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <span>Ashley Ford</span><br/></td>
            <td><a href="#" id="del">x</a>
        </td></tr>  
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate `id` values in the same document. Change it to a class name.

Comment: Difference between id and class are the very basic of java script..please read documents carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have same `id` for more than one element ..for that you have to use `class`
1.Change your `id="del"` to `class="del"`
2.Try this function

```
 $(function() {
      $(".del").click(function() {
      $('#load').fadeIn();
      $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
    $('#load').fadeOut();

    });
     });
```

Comment: Great that help me a lot. But now I would like to slideUp entire row of a table. But if I choose     $("tr"). the entire table slidesUp.

Comment: Try $(this).parent().parent().slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But instead of slideUp I use FadeOut, because it was better animation for table.

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery docs for the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) (emphasis added):

> If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that
>   use that ID will only select the **first matched element** in the DOM.

You can change your `#del` elements to use a class name (or some other common characteristic) instead:

```
<a href="#" class="del">x</a>
```

And modify your selector accordingly:

```
$(".del").click(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

---

As a side note, you have two functions that will be executed on DOM ready. You can combine them into one. Just move the `$('#load').hide();` into the other DOM ready event handler.

And it's invalid HTML to have a `div` as a child of a `table` element.

Comment: As you can see I change the original post code, I want to SlideUp entire row(<tr>). But I have problem, with selecting the right tag in the table. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As other have stated, each element `id` should be unique. If you need to group a bunch of elements, that is what the element `class` is for.